# How to quickly delete all sms on android

Tags: java, android, sms

How can I delete all sms in content://sms quickly.

Currently I am using:

```
while (c.moveToNext()) {
    int idi = c.getInt(0);
    getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse("content://sms/" + idi), null, null);
}
```

but if there are a lot of messages the procedure, it can take a long time.

I need to remove absolutely all messages.

Is there a faster way?

Comment: I don't know if it's privileged operation or not, but clear the data of the message storage maybe?

Comment: You could also thread the deleting into it's own thread, so the app deletes them in the background and still is responsive. Not any faster, but the app itself won't slow down in responsiveness.

Comment: Yes, i know but app must wait to delete all sms because next procedure must work on empty inbox etc...

Comment: Can someone in this case provide a way to delete the conversation as I delete messages in the above code (in a loop)?

Comment: I tried:
getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse("content://sms/"), null, null);
and work -deleted all messages immediately. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tried it, but can you use the Uri of just "content://sms" (without specifying individual message ids)?

Can peek into the content provider code here: https://gitorious.org/0xdroid/packages_providers_telephonyprovider/source/50b2f39df213be0e5a31226582a4792681a9f564:src/com/android/providers/telephony/SmsProvider.java#L485

Comment: just google "SmsProvider.java"
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/providers/TelephonyProvider/+/master/src/com/android/providers/telephony/SmsProvider.java